# (Reddit API) How to get a list of subreddits user is subscribed to, using snoowrap?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, reddit

So I'm using snoowrap to write a Chrome extension that gets a list of subreddits the user is subscribed, and subscribes to them on a different account.

I'm trying to get the list of subreddits currently but can't figure out how to do it. I've tried simply getting the JSON from https://www.reddit.com/subreddits/mine.json, which returns an empty object (persumably because no auth) and I have no idea how to do it via snoowrap. I looked through the documentation and can't find an option for it.

My code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var login = document.getElementById('login');
  login.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const r = new snoowrap({
      userAgent: '???',
      clientId: '<id>',
      clientSecret: '<clientsecret>',
      username: '<username-here>',
      password: '<password-here>'
    });

    r.getHot().map(post => post.title).then(console.log);
  });

  var getSubs = document.getElementById('get-subs');
  getSubs.addEventListener('click', function() {

    fetch('https://www.reddit.com/subreddits/mine.json')
      .then(function(data) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error');
      });

  });
});
```

Not sure how else to try. Anyone have suggestions? I'd like to use snoowrap for this ideally.

Answer (score 1):

When using snoowrap as API wrapper, after connecting to the api with:

```
const r = new snoowrap({...});
```

They provide a function for getting your own subscribed subreddits:

```
r.getSubscriptions();
```

This will return a `Listing` Object, which you can use like an Array.